# Force key-frame with h264 and udpsrc in Gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, keyframe

I'm trying to transmit via UDP a h264 encoded video using Gstreamer.

It works fine but only when I start the client before the server. I think it may be something related to key-frame, Its possible that the client is waiting for this mark, and when started at first the server it only sends one.

Here I attach server Gstreamer command, is there any parameter that indicate the number of frames between two keyframes?

gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! "video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,format=(string)YV12,framerate=30/1" ! imxipuvideotransform ! "video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=(string)I420,framerate=30/1" ! imxvpuenc_h264 idr-interval=0 ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! udpsink host=MULTICAST multicast-iface=eth0 force-ipv4=true port=5010 sync=false

Thanks a lot for the answers!

Comment: Can you share your server pipeline? I will try to reproduce it.

Comment: The command I put in my question is the command running in the server, I just found the solution, I have to change "idr-interval" parameter for some value different than 0. Thanks!